# pass data to the wizard odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I created an wizard and I want to get all the data from my table and put it in my wizard. I can not make a loop with my result in xml. Have you any idea of ​​what I can do it Odoo 11 please.

Here is my code:

my model

```
class PopMessage(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "custom.pop.message"

    def get_values(self):
        cron = self.env['cron.stock.limit'].search([])
        for i in range(len(cron)):
            res.append({'quantity': cron[i].quantity})
        return res

    test = fields.Char(string='Test', default=get_values, readonly=True)
```

Comment: Can you please write wizard code over here?

Answer (score 0):

Here the wizard

```
<record id="custom_pop_message_wizard_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">custom.pop.message</field>
    <field name="model">custom.pop.message</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Message">
            <field name="test"/> <!--this fields is correctly displayed-->
             <t t-foreach="test" t-as="t"> <!-- but i can loop on it here-->
                  <span t-esc="t" />
             </t>
            <footer>
                <button string="OK" class="btn-primary" special="cancel" />
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
<record id="action_cron_popup" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Produits</field>
    <field name="res_model">custom.pop.message</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="custom_pop_message_wizard_view_form"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```